# Consigo desabilitar o SPDY num request HTTPS do Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

Se eu acessar minha aplicação por https:// no GAE, ela é servida automaticamente por SPDY para browsers compatíveis. Isso é bom. Mas eu queria saber se consigo desabilitar esse comportamento e usar HTTPS com 1.1 mesmo normal. Algum header ou configuração que eu possa fazer?

Pra deixar claro, estou perguntando de desabilitar no servidor, pra todos os clientes, não no meu browser.

Answer (score 1):

No [chrome](https://chrome.google.com) você vai ter que fazer via linha de comando:

```
chrome.exe --use-spdy=off
```

No [firefox](https://www.mozilla.org), você pode ir na tela de configurações acessando `about:config` e ajustar a configuração `network.http.spdy.enabled` para `false`

Comment: Obrigado pela tentativa, mas minha pergunta era sobre desabilitar o SPDY no servidor, não no browser. No browser ok, é fácil, eu faço isso aqui. Mas queria desabilitar pra todos o clientes, não só pra mim.

Answer (score 0):

Ressucitando o tópico: Para o spdy funcionar é preciso compilar o mod_spdy no apache, por exemplo.  Tente desabilitá-lo.

Comment: Não entendi como desabilitar.. Se compilar o mod_spdy desabilita o SPDY? É isso?

Comment: Obrigado pela tentativa, mas a pergunta é sobre o Google App Engine, não sobre o mod_spdy do Apache